# Calling a web service from C++

Tags: c++, web-services, client

I have a simple web service running on a JBoss server. Now I need to access it from C++, Microsoft VC++ 2010, to be precise. Being new to web services in general, I googled my problem, but found that most people advised to to "Add Web Reference", something that appears to be gone since VS2008. So I was wondering if somebody could give me a few pointers on what the easiest way to call a web service from C++ would be.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Add Web Reference is the method used when you are writing c# application. But what you are talking about is C++. Which protocol does your JBoss Server follow?And "Add Web Reference" mehod still exists in VS2008/VS2010.

Comment: What kind of "web service"? SOAP? REST style?

Comment: Not on a regular C++ console application project, it doesn't.

Comment: You cannot do add web reference on a c++ console app even in VS2005 i guess

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can try [gSoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html)

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend gSOAP. It can be a handful but it works. Point it at a WSDL and it'll generate proxies that you can use in your client code.

It's free if you are producing open source work as well.

Comment: And assuming that I would not be working on an open source project..?

Comment: Well then, if it is commercial you'll probably need to pay for it. 


See here:
http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soaplicense.html

Bojan's option is usable as well.

Answer (score 1):

I used the sproxy tool to generate a C++/ATL header file for my web service. The sproxy tool comes with the ATL Server source code (CodePlex). Although the project's been dead for a few years so I had to do the work of manually converting the project to VS2010 (it wouldn't convert automatically using the conversion wizard), but now it works and I was able to call my web service from a console app with just a few lines of code.